# How to draw partially transparent bitmap inside a fully transparent window?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, dxgi

I have a fully transparent window:

```
wClass.cbClsExtra = NULL;
wClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wClass.cbWndExtra = NULL;
wClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
wClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
wClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
wClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
wClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandleA(0);
wClass.lpfnWndProc = &Overlay::WinProc;
wClass.lpszClassName = overlay_window_name.c_str();
wClass.lpszMenuName = overlay_window_name.c_str();
wClass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
cid = RegisterClassEx(&wClass);

DWORD ex_style = 0;
DWORD style = 0;


ex_style = WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED;
style = WS_POPUP;


m_overlay_window = CreateWindowEx(ex_style, overlay_window_name.c_str(), overlay_window_name.c_str(), style, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, this);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_overlay_window, 0, 0, LWA_ALPHA);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(m_overlay_window, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0), LWA_COLORKEY);
```

I am creating swap chain:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC desc{};

desc.Windowed = TRUE;
desc.BufferCount = 2;
desc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
desc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;      //multisampling setting
desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;    //vendor-specific flag
desc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
desc.OutputWindow = hwnd;

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL levels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1
};

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL feature_level;

UINT device_flags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
    nullptr,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE::D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    nullptr,
    device_flags,
    levels,
    ARRAYSIZE(levels),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &desc,
    &m_swap_chain,
    &m_device,
    &feature_level,
    &m_context
);
```

and then I want to draw half-transparent bitmap(through which I can see content of other windows):

```
m_render_target->DrawBitmap(m_bitmap, rect, 0.5, D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_LINEAR);
```

but this bitmap always not transparent. Only thing is going for him he becomes darker. May be something wrong with window or swap chain Im creating?